# jQuery click event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to hide an element by using click event, but the click event doesn't trigger.

Here is the code:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#myButtonID").click(function(){  
        $("p").hide();  
    });  
 });  
</script> 


<p>Lorem Ipsum </p> 
<a href="#" id="myButtonID">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works but it may be reloading the page. The `//code.jquery.com` will load in `http` or `https` depending on the protocol your page is using. Try:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#myButtonID").click(function(e){ 
        //prevent default element action
        e.preventDefault();
        $("p").hide();  
    });  
 });
```

or, if you want to use a shorter ready function and speed up jQuery a bit with `.on`:

[jQuery .on vs click handler speed test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-vs-click-handler)

```
$(function () {
    $("#myButtonID").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2ymF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` from the selector

`$("#myButtonID").click(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

forgot the # in your selector:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $("#myButtonID").click(function(){  
    $("p").hide();  
});  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: thinking if it could be jquery ui library, I recently changed from googleapis to the above (jQuery CDN)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the hash character used to signify your selecting by an elements id.

```
$("#myButtonID").click(function(){  
        $("p").hide();  
    });
```